# Error with chrome CertificatProvider

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, x509certificate, smartcard, client-certificates

I try to install chrome extension that use the CertificateProvider of chrome to show the list of certificats. this is the background code :

**background.js** of chrome certificateProvider but it return this log error:  **Cannot read property 'onCertificatesRequested' of undefined**

```javascript
function onCertificatesRejected(rejectedCerts) {
    // If certificates were rejected by the API, log an error, for example.
    console.error(rejectedCerts.length + ' certificates were rejected.');
  }

  function reportCertificates(reportCallback) {
    var certs = [];
    // Fill |certs| with all certificates that this Extension provides.
    // For example:
    var certInfo = {
      certificate: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
      hash: {
        name: "SHA256",
      } 
    };
    certs.push(certInfo);
    reportCallback(certs, function(rejectedCerts) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        // Handle API errors, like argument type errors.
        return;
      }
      if (rejectedCerts.length !== 0)
        onCertificatesRejected(rejectedCerts);
    });
  }

  // Returns a private key handle for the given DER-encoded certificate.
  // |certificate| is an ArrayBuffer.
  function getPrivateKeyHandle(certificate) {}

  // If required, prepends |digest| with a DigestInfo and pads the result
  // according to the key type and the given Hash function.
  // |digest| is an ArrayBuffer. |hash| is a Hash. Returns an ArrayBuffer.
  function prepareDigest(digest, hash) {}

  // Signs |digest| with the given private key. |digest| is an ArrayBuffer.
  // Returns the signature as ArrayBuffer.
  function signDigest(privateKey, digest) {}

  function reportSignature(signRequest, reportCallback) {
    // Look up the handle to the private key of |signRequest.certificate|.
    var key = getPrivateKeyHandle(signRequest.certificate);
    if (!key) {
      // Handle if the key isn't available.
      console.error('Key for requested certificate no available.');

      // Abort the request by reporting the error to the API.
      reportCallback();
      return;
    }

    var preparedDigest = prepareDigest(signRequest.digest, signRequest.hash);
    var signature = signDigest(key, preparedDigest);
    reportCallback(signature);
  }

  chrome.certificateProvider.onCertificatesRequested.addListener(reportCertificates);
  chrome.certificateProvider.onSignDigestRequested.addListener( reportSignature);
```

Comment: Usually it means you didn't add the API in `"permissions"` in manifest.json. Also, the documentaion says certificateProvider is ChromeOS-only.

Comment: I need some thing like this but for chrome Windows.. is there an other API chrome that show the list of certificats???

Comment: `certificateProvider` is an API to _add_ certificates, not query existing ones.